# Unknown exception in Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::Application::OnLaunchedProtected

Tags: windows-store-apps

Store certification testing is reporting that my app crashes on startup. I have not been able to reproduce the error on my desktop pc or Surface RT so far. The app does implement search contract. Please have a look at the [minidump here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F3D91D8E2EEF858A!4485&authkey=!AIy8OJaaHEzZ8so).

**Update: I have attached [a link to the source code](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F3D91D8E2EEF858A!4498&authkey=!AP7OcsmHUDP42JE), please have a go and see if you can reproduce the error or spot any obvious mistakes!**

> Instruction at
>   Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledErrorForUserCode+7a
>   in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an
>   unknown exception (0xc000027b)

```
combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal+112     aaaaaaaa     aaaaaaaa     aaaaaaaa     0056516c   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\winrt\error\error.cpp @ 853 
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ErrorHelper::ProcessUnhandledErrorForUserCode+7a     aaaaaaaa     005b3bdc     00000000     aaaaaaaa    
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::Application::OnLaunchedProtected+7b     050726ac     aaaaaaaa     0079d280     00000000    
Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::FrameworkView::OnActivated+b3     00798b40     00000000     04b1ee80     6e8f2f42    
Windows_UI_Xaml!`Microsoft::WRL::Callback<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::LoadMoreItemsResult>,DirectUI::ListViewBase,Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::LoadMoreItemsResult> *,enum ABI::Windows::Foundation::AsyncStatus>'::`2'::ComObject::Invoke+19     050b45d8     00798b40     005b3bdc     00798b48    
twinapi!Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::ITypedEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Search::SearchPane *,Windows::ApplicationModel::Search::SearchPaneQueryChangedEventArgs *> >::DoInvoke<`Microsoft::WRL::EventSource<Windows::Foundation::ITypedEventHandler<Windows::ApplicationModel::Search::SearchPane *,Windows::ApplicationModel::Search::SearchPaneQueryChangedEventArgs *> >::InvokeAll<CSearchPaneClient *,CSearchPaneQueryChangedEventArgs *>'::`3'::<lambda_AB69E19221CB48D5> >+48     aaaaaaaa     00798b40     005b3bdc     04b1f0c4   d:\win8_gdr.public.x86fre\sdk\inc\wrl\event.h @ 928 + e 
twinapi!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Activate+ab     0079e370     00000000     005b3bdc     aaaaaaaa   d:\win8_gdr\shell\coreapplication\application\lib\coreapplicationview.cpp @ 874 
rpcrt4!Invoke+2a     6e8dbd11     04b1f0c8     aaaaaaaa     aaaaaaaa    
rpcrt4!NdrStubCall2+33b     050cf998     050d3e80     aaaaaaaa     04b1f310    
combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+c1     050cf998     aaaaaaaa     050d3e80     aaaaaaaa   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\ndr\ndrole\stub.cxx @ 1507 + 75caf44b 
combase!SyncStubInvoke+d0     aaaaaaaa     aaaaaaaa     00580678     6e8d4430   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx @ 1263 + d 
combase!CCtxComChnl::ContextInvoke+213     04b1f4dc     75c2189c     050d3e80     aaaaaaaa   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\ctxchnl.cxx @ 1344 + 96 
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+10b     00000000     00000000     00000010     aaaaaaaa    
user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+16b     0058e760     00000000     0058e760     0058e768    
combase!ComInvoke+171     04b1f878     00000000     04b1f840     75c1eb0d   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx @ 1575 
combase!CComApartment::ASTAHandleMessage+2c     aaaaaaaa     007976f0     04b1f904     aaaaaaaa   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\applicationsta.cpp @ 2301 
combase!ASTAWaitContext::Wait+39b     04b1f878     aaaaaaaa     007976f0     aaaaaaaa   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\applicationsta.cpp @ 850 
combase!ASTAWaitInNewContext+78     aaaaaaaa     aaaaaaaa     00000000     75c0d900   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\applicationsta.cpp @ 2547 + 14 
combase!ASTAThreadWaitForHandles+4a     00000000     aaaaaaaa     00000000     007976f0   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\applicationsta.cpp @ 2773 + 36 
combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+a4     00000008     aaaaaaaa     aaaaaaaa     007976f0   d:\win8_gdr\com\combase\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 120 + 65 
twinapi!`Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::RuntimeClassInitialize'::`55'::<lambda_A2234BA2CCD64E2C>::operator()+39     00000000     04b1f9c8     750d5a10     007976d0   d:\win8_gdr\shell\coreapplication\application\lib\coreapplicationview.cpp @ 552 
twinapi!`Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationViewAgileContainer::RuntimeClassInitialize'::`55'::<lambda_A2234BA2CCD64E2C>::<helper_func>+e     007976d0     00000000     00000000     001beeb4   d:\win8_gdr\shell\coreapplication\application\lib\coreapplicationview.cpp @ 613 + e 
SHCore!SHWaitForThreadWithWakeMask+13b     aaaaaaaa     04b1fa18     77c8ac69     001beeb4    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e     001beeb4     aaaaaaaa     00000000     00000000    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+72     750d5931     001beeb4     aaaaaaaa     77d01d8e    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b 

Image Name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll   Symbol Type:  PDB 
Base address: 0x00905a4d   Time Stamp:  Thu Sep 20 06:25:43 2012  
Checksum: 0x00000000   Comments:   
COM DLL: False   Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
ISAPIExtension: False   File Description:  Windows.UI.Xaml dll 
ISAPIFilter: False   File Version:  6.2.9200.16420 (win8_gdr.120919-1813) 
Managed DLL: False   Internal Name:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll 
VB DLL: False   Legal Copyright:  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
Loaded Image Name:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll   Legal Trademarks:   
Mapped Image Name:  c:\symcache\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll\505A9AC7a54000\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll   Original filename:  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll 
Module name:  Windows_UI_Xaml   Private Build:   
Single Threaded:  False   Product Name:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System 
Module Size:  10,33 MBytes   Product Version:  6.2.9200.16420 
Symbol File Name:  c:\symcache\windows.ui.xaml.pdb\F3AFE9A212494DCAB4068DD4A4A781232\windows.ui.xaml.pdb   Special Build:  &
```

**Edit: I was able to make the app crash locally by enabling LuaPriv in Application Verifier. If i disable it it does not crash. I am not sure this is the same crash because I am running into an issue where AppVerif can not write logs. Any help? Do certification testers run with LuaPriv? I am trying to figure out how to run Standard User Analyzer on my app, any hints how to do this? My app does write to ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings with an implementation of IsolatedStorageHelper I found somewhere. Is this an issue?**

Comment: Have you run your application in the Windows App Certification Kit?

Comment: Yes, no issues when I run this.

Comment: I seem to have encountered this bug... Code works great for a while, then now this exception occurs and I can't get it to go away. My app wont even run now... Anyone figure out a solution?

Comment: I suspect this call stack might cover several different cases. Based on my issue with missing resources maybe you could search through your xaml and look for similar issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app got certified on the next submission. What I discovered was a missing string resource for a label for en-US using the x:Uid directive. By changing to this language on my computer I did get a call stack enabling me to find the missing string. Too bad I didn't save the call stack so I could post it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same chrash in previous versions of applications, it's a some bug in runtime, it's been resolved in the meantime,

Here are the details with the workaround:

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=0dcffd79-3848-4cc3-839d-ab7d3544f80a

Comment: Thanks for the tip, going to attempt another submission.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue come up after my app was working great. Then all of a sudden this exception would occur every time I ran the app. I found that if I went into "Metro" and Uninstalled the app, the ran it again the issue was resolved. It's apparently a bug in WinRT that once it occurs it gets stuck, and only a uninstall/reinstall will fix it.

My experiences were on my Dev machine, so I don't know if this would fix it in a Production environment, but it should. Hope this helps someone!

UPDATE: I still got this after a little while, and tried on a fresh install of Win8/VS'13 and it occurs there too. This is apparently a bug in WinRT after all.... Now if I can only find a work around...